# how to disconnect the webcam in webcam.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, webcam.js

Does anyone know how can I disconnect the webcam in webcam.js?

I'm using Webcam.attach(webcam.js) to connect to the webcam. However, I try to use webcam.reset() to disconnect the webcam and it's seem not working. The webcam is still on and the tab of the browser show webcam is connected (red dot showing on the tab).

Does anyone know how can I disconnect it in webcam.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried `Webcam.reset( '#my_camera' )` with no problem.
Tested on: https://pixlcore.com/demos/webcamjs/demos/basic.html

Did you check for console errors?

Comment: reset does not take any parameters. It will shutdown live preview from all added DOM elements: https://github.com/jhuckaby/webcamjs/blob/master/DOCS.md#reset-shutdown